# How to store unknown number of columns from mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table and I am querying it through PHP. The query is like below

```
 SELECT min(Age) , max(Age) , min(Workexp) , max(Workexp) FROM data_table
```

Depending on user's choice, it may have to return more or less min/max pairs but it will always return 1 row only.

Had the number of columns been constant, I could have simply used below to store the results in an array and use it.

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
    {$SelFieldNameArray[] = array('field_name1' => $obj->field_name1, 'field_name2' => $obj->field_name2);}
```

However because of variable number of columns, I am not able to do this here. Could anyone please help me regarding this. Thank you.

Comment: if you can show table pls

Comment: Why not just pull an array in the first place using [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)?

Comment: What exactly you want to show or you want to do with your records?

Comment: the documentation for `mysql_fetch_assoc` is right next to `mysql_fetch_object`, it's not clear how you could miss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are selecting dynamic number of columns in your query.

You can retrieve them this way:

```
$SelFieldNameArray = array();
//MYSQL_NUM retrieves all your rows in numbered indexes so you can
//easily loop through them
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_NUM); 
foreach($row as $k=>$v) {
    $SelFieldNameArray[] = array('field_name'.($k+1)=>$row[$k]);
}
```

Output:

```
array 
  0 => 
    array
      'field_name1' => 5
  1 => 
    array 
      'field_name2' => 10
  //...etc.
```

#### Note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thank you for understanding my problem. I don't want to use associative array with keys as field1, field2 as it might cause problems in retrieval. A simple array will suffice for me, so I am using mysql_fetch_row.  I will change all of mysql_* to mysqli_*. Thanks again.

Comment: @John MYSQL_NUM does the same, returns you the numbered index 0, 1 etc. You can see the above code does not make use of any field names while retrieving.

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch the result as an associative and use that.

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $SelFieldNameArray[] = $result;
}
```

Comment: Why bother populating another array? Just use `$result` as the `$selFieldNameArray`.

Comment: That would not be the same structure as in the question. But you might be right by assuming that that is actually what he needs :)

Comment: Who knows what he wants, could be either :)

Answer (score 3):

**Firstly:** Please switch to using [mysqli_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)* since [mysql_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)* is deprecated.

Try this query which defines attribute names for your min and max selects

SELECT
min(Age) AS minAge,
max(Age) AS maxAge,
min(Workexp) AS minWorkexp,
max(Workexp)  AS maxWorkexp
FROM data_table

Now your 1 row, which should have had 4 columns to begin with, should have those 4 attributes named after the given attribute names.

So when requested as associative array (i.e. using [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc)), you can access them directly:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo 'minAge = '.$result['minAge']
    .'maxAge = '.$result['maxAge']
    .'minWorkexp = '.$result['minWorkexp']
    .'maxWorkexp = '.$result['maxWorkexp'];
```

To give it to you as an object, use [mysqli_fetch_object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php):

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
echo 'minAge = '.$result->minAge
    .'maxAge = '.$result->maxAge
    .'minWorkexp = '.$result->minWorkexp
    .'maxWorkexp = '.$result->maxWorkexp;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if it returns only one row, you do not need while. Second, you can use mysql_fetch_assoc to fetch both column names and values. For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT min(Age) , max(Age) , min(Workexp) , max(Workexp) FROM data_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$columns = array_keys($row);
print_r($columns); //prints the column names
echo $columns[2]; //prints the name of the third column
echo count($columns); //prints total number of columns

print_r($row); //prints all columns and their values
echo $row[$columns[2]]; //prints what is in the third column

foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
  echo $key.":".$value; //prints min(Age):1 for example
}
```

NOTE: Do not use **mysql_** function since they are deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I achieved it as below $row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql1)); . This should work since I will only have 1 row. I will change all of mysql_* to mysqli_*

Comment: Number of rows makes no difference between mysql_fetch_row and mysql_fetch_assoc. Only difference is the type of output (row gives object and assoc gives associative array). The function is 100% same.